# Adding DTPerformanceSession.framework causes app to crash on run

Tags: xcode, macos

I added DTPerformanceSession.framework to the OSX app Build Phases and when I run the app it crashes with the following error:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x7fff5fc0109c:  int3   
0x7fff5fc0109d:  nop
```

Console message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DTPerformanceSession.framework/Versions/A/DTPerformanceSession
  Referenced from: /Users/Danger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HSCountingInputStream-dbhgckaaqtaiqueimpvpxllvygvt/Build/Products/Debug/HSCountingInputStream
  Reason: image not found
```

Back trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x5e40d, 0x00007fff5fc0109d dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc0109d dyld`dyld_fatal_error + 1
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5fc02138 dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 79
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5fc059bd dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2733
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5fc01397 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 761
    frame #4: 0x00007fff5fc0105e dyld`_dyld_start + 54
```

Note: DTPerformanceSession.framework is at path:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the great page: [Using code generated flags to debug with Instruments](http://finalize.com/2013/01/31/using-code-generated-flags-to-debug-with-instruments/). Basically one just needs to add the framework, build and remove the framework, it is needed only for Xcode to find the include and only once. Alternatively add the framework and mark it "Optional".