# Using DTPerformanceSession.framework for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode

Newbie iOS developer so bear with me here. :)

I was refering to [wiki](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewInstruments/NewFeatures40/NewFeatures40.html):

It introduces the DTPerformanceSession to invoke instruments like TimeProfiler etc from your code.
The frameowork is not present under

```
/Library/Developer/4.0/Instruments/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework.
I am using XCode 5.1 on Mavericks.
```

Only x86_64 version of the DTPerformanceSession.framework is available on my machine and I get linking errors when I try to build my app for iOS device or simulator.
What am I missing here?

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework/DTPerformanceSession, 
file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework/DTPerformanceSession
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"DTPerformanceSessionStop(void const*, __CFArray const*, __CFError**)", referenced from:
-[CalculatorTestClientStressTests endDTPerformanceSession::::] in CalculatorTestClientStressTests.o
"DTPerformanceSessionSave(void const*, __CFString const*, __CFError**)", referenced from:
-[CalculatorTestClientStressTests endDTPerformanceSession::::] in CalculatorTestClientStressTests.o
"DTPerformanceSessionAddInstrument(void const*, __CFString const*, __CFDictionary const*, void (*)(__CFString const*, __CFError*), __CFError**)", referenced from:
-[CalculatorTestClientStressTests initDTPerformanceSession::] in CalculatorTestClientStressTests.o
"DTPerformanceSessionCreate(__CFString const*, __CFString const*, __CFDictionary const*, __CFError**)", referenced from:
-[CalculatorTestClientStressTests initDTPerformanceSession::] in CalculatorTestClientStressTests.o
"DTPerformanceSessionStart(void const*, __CFArray const*, __CFError**)", referenced from:
-[CalculatorTestClientStressTests initDTPerformanceSession::] in CalculatorTestClientStressTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this for the first time myself. It would appear that `DTPerformanceSession` doesn't support iOS (yet):

> file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework/DTPerformanceSession
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework/DTPerformanceSession: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

As you can see it only supports 64bit OSX, unfortunately.

Comment: Correction: It seems some of its features *are* usable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742378/adding-dtperformancesession-framework-causes-app-to-crash-on-run